# Bitnami kibana not found after restarting the VM

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, bitnami

I am running bitnami ELK stack on azure. https://bitnami.com/stack/elk

I restarted the VM and now trying to access kibana but it's giving me below error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /elk/app/kibana was not found on this server.
```

Previously, it was working fine.

I tried restarting apache, kibana and elasticsearch but no luck.

Elasticsearch is running fine.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please verify that the Bitnami's Apache is running in your machine? You can use the following command to get the status of all the services `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`. If they all are currently running, did you make any change in the Apache's configuration that could cause this issue?

Comment: @JotaMartos: I checked that as well. It's running. Elasticsearch is also running fine. I just restarted the VM on azure.

Comment: Did you make any change in the Apache's configuration? The /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file should include a "/opt/bitnami/kibana/apache-conf/kibana.conf" file that redirects all the requests to /elk to the kibana server. Apart from that, can you access kibana locally? `curl -I localhost:5601`